# Why does the contour plot that I do in Origin Lab look like this?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, contour, dat-protocol, originlab

I have a question. I imported into origin lab a .dat that I exported from a wolfram mathematica contour plot before and when I do the contour plot in origin lab the plots have some vertical lines that in mathematics they don't.

[mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyzPT.png)
[originlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA3Qp.png)

How can i fix this? any ideas?

Comment: Without any code to study I am guessing that Mathematica generated thousands or millions of different levels and colors and shading to make that plot. Origin Lab looked at all that fabricated stuff and thought that was VERY IMPORTANT and made its own plot. To fix this I'd suggest studying https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html and click the orange Details and options and learn how to turn off things like `ContourShading` and set a small list of `Countours` that displays the essential behavior you want to communicate. Either that or pass the function to Origin Lab to plot.